# SQL select filter

Tags: sql, select

I have this code that outputs numbers of cancelled trip by days:

```
select request_at, count(*) as cancelled 
from trip
where status = 'cancelled_by_client' 
   or status = 'cancelled_by_driver'
group by request_at order by request_at
```

It works, but, when there is no cancelled trip, it outputs nothing.

I want it to output 'data' and 0 as a value of cancelled.

How can I change my code to do this?

Comment: Do you want to show just dates where there are trips (whether cancelled or not) or all dates, regardless of whether there was a trip on that date? If the second option, presumably you want min and max date boundaries?

Comment: i want something like(there is only 2 dates in table)
'2022-10-12' 5
'2022-10-13' 0

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select request_at, 
Sum(Case when 
    status = 'cancelled_by_client' or status = 'cancelled_by_driver' 
    then 1 else 0 end
   ) as cancelled 
from trip
group by request_at 
order by request_at
```

Comment: What if there is another where clause?

Comment: Sorry @sa-es-ir , I don’t understand your comment. Are you assuming requirements that the questioner hasn’t mentioned? Even if you are, how would having another where clause be an issue/relevant to my answer?

Comment: You're right, I think I got the question wrong. By the way, I meant if there was a where clause that caused no rows to match then there is no result. But it seems OP still wants a default row in the output.